# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component. To locate the bad setState() call inside `MyApp`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

When I go from my main page to login page this error happens.I use Header component almost everywhere as a child component in my app.

Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different component (`MyApp`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MyApp`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

I tried to add props.user as useEffect dependency but didnt work

Header.js

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const isLoggedIn = useSelector(getLogged());
  console.log("login:", isLoggedIn);

  return (
    <div className={style}>
      
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

Login page

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../../components/Layout/Header";
import LoginPage from "../../components/Login/LoginPage";
import { fetchUser, wrapper } from "../../redux";
import { useStore } from "react-redux";

let userId;

export default function Login(props) {
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);
  console.log("State on render4", useStore().getState());

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("props:", props.user);
  }, [props.user]);

  const changeId = (given) => {
    setId(given);
    userId = id;
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <LoginPage change={changeId} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) => async () => {
    const user = await store.dispatch(fetchUser(userId));
    console.log("State on server4", store.getState());

    return {
      props: {
        user: user,
      },
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: What should render `Header`? because right now it is just rendering an empty div

Comment: there's divs and next/link inside it, I deleted it

Comment: Could you look at it btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75734149/i-cant-get-session-of-next-auth-js-in-app-js

Answer (score 0):

try to put your component in the same folder of app.js for header component do not use below

```
import Header from "../../components/Layout/Header";
```

but you should use below line

```
import Header from "components/Layout/Header";
```

this mean you put components folder with app.js in the same folder with index.js file
try this soluotion and inform me the result

Comment: But app.js is in the pages file and pages,components is different folders, Do you think problem will be solved if I create a page for Header and use this header page inside of another page (instead of using header component inside page)

Comment: Could you look at it btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75734149/i-cant-get-session-of-next-auth-js-in-app-js