# I can't get session of next-auth.js in _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have two provider but I can't use two of them at the same time when i try to log user using useSession there's an existencetime but not a user(empty object returns)
I have backend that returns the user data

_app.js

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, session, ...rest }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Component {...props.pageProps} key={router.asPath} />
      </SessionProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Login handler in the login page

```
const loginHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      username: loginValues.username,
      password: loginValues.password,
      redirect: false,
    });
  };
```

[...nextauth].js

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "username",
          type: "text",
        },
        password: {
          label: "password",
          type: "password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { username, password } = credentials;
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password,
          }),
        });
        const user = await res.json();

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not updating the session you are just returning the user from the response so you have to use [callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks) to achieve that.

> **JWT callback**
> This callback is called whenever a JSON Web Token is created (i.e. at sign in) or updated (i.e whenever a session is accessed in the client). The returned value will be encrypted, and it is stored in a cookie.

> **Session callback**
> The session callback is called whenever a session is checked. By default, only a subset of the token is returned for increased security. If you want to make something available you added to the token (like access_token and user.id from above) via the jwt() callback, you have to explicitly forward it here to make it available to the client.

```js
 callbacks: {
    async jwt({ user, token }) {
      //   update token if user is returned
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      //   return final_token
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      //  update session from token
      session.user = token.user; // you can add the properties you want instead of overwriting the session.user
      return session;
    },
  },
```

Comment: I solved this thanks but now even if i enter the right user values it returns this error user: {timestamp: '...', status: 404, error: 'Not Found', message: 'No message available', path: '/login', do you think this error is relevant with the backend error message